# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError:TypeError: open() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, discord.py

i am trying to make a discord.py economy, here's the code

```
async def get_bank_data():
        with open(bandata, "r") as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        return users
```

it however returns with "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: open() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given", is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Example of the simple command could solve your issue:

```py
@discord.ext.commands.command()
async def ping(ctx: discord.ext.commands.Context):
    await ctx.send('pong')
```